# Задача на pascal, китайский гороскоп

Tags: pascal

Что-то до меня не доходит, надо с помощью только div, mod и case решить задачу

60-летний цикл состоящий из 12-летних подциклов из цветов: зеленый, красный, желтый, белый и черный.

В каждом подцикле годы носят названия: крыса, корова, тигр, заяц, дракон, змея, лошадь, овца, обезьяна, курица, собака и свинья

Например 1984 - зеленая крыса

Comment: один я не вижу вопроса?

Comment: @teanЫЧ и что, первый раз, что ли? Тут хоть догадаться несложно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил попробовать написать программу на паскале (лучше бы я не пытался -- язык для мазохистов).

```
program gor;
var year, year1: Integer;
    color : Integer;
    beast : Integer;

begin
    Write('Year>');
    ReadLn(year);
    year1 := ((year - 1984) mod 60 + 60) mod 60;
    beast := year1 mod  12;
    color := (year1 div 12) mod 5;
    Write(year, ' - год ');
    if beast in [2, 3, 4] then
        case color of
        0: Write('зелёного');
        1: Write('красного');
        2: Write('жёлтого');
        3: Write('белого');
        4: Write('чёрного');
        end
    else
        case color of
        0: Write('зелёной');
        1: Write('красной');
        2: Write('жёлтой');
        3: Write('белой');
        4: Write('чёрной');
        end;
    Write(' ');
    case beast of
    0: Write('крысы');
    1: Write('коровы');
    2: Write('тигра');
    3: Write('зайца');
    4: Write('дракона');
    5: Write('змеи');
    6: Write('лошади');
    7: Write('овцы');
    8: Write('обезьяны');
    9: Write('курицы');
    10: Write('собаки');
    11: Write('свиньи');
    end;
    WriteLn();
end.
```

Допускаю, что этих "кошек просто надо уметь готовить", но мне уж как-то лучше говядина со свининой.

```
# vim: set fileencoding=utf-8:
year = int(input('Year>'))
year1 = ((year - 1984) % 60 + 60) % 60
(beast, color) = (year1 % 12, year1 / 12 % 5)
s=str(year) + ' - год '
if beast in (2, 3, 4): c = ('зелёного', 'красного', 'жёлтого', 'белого', 'чёрного')
else :                 c = ('зелёной', 'красной', 'жёлтой', 'белой', 'чёрной')
s += c[color] + ' '
s += ('крысы', 'коровы', 'тигра', 'зайца', 'дракона', 'змеи', 'лошади', 'овцы', 'обезьяны', 'курицы', 'собаки', 'свиньи')[beast]
print s
```

Answer (score 0):

Я подозреваю, что будет что-то такое.

```
fullCycle:=60;          // Полный цикл
fullSubcycle:=12;       // Полный подцикл
fullColorSubcycle:=5*2; // Полный цветовой подцикл. В соответствии с [вики][1], цвета идут 2 года подряд, поэтому умножили количество элементов на 2.
currentYear;        // Год, для которого надо определить описание.

//извлекаем текущий цикл, например, если вычисляем для 90 года, то результат выражения будет 30, т.е. отнимаем все полные прошедшие периоды
currentCycle := currentYear - (currentYear div fullCycle)*fullCycle;

//вычисляем текущий год подцикла, т.е. если на предыдущем шаге был 30 год цикла, то сейчас получаем, что сейчас 6 год подцикла. Это значение всегда будет от 0 до 11.
curYear:= currentCycle mod fullSubcycle;
//Применяем case и определяем имя имя года
case..

//вычисляем цвет текущего года
curColor:= curYear mod fullColorSubcycle;
//Применяем case и определяем цвет года
case..
```

Удачи!

Comment: Вики, может и двухлетний, а в условиях @Fangog, как я понял, цвет тянется 12 лет.

Comment: я тоже так сначала подумал, но мне стало неясно почему цветов 5, а полный цикл 60 лет

Comment: Декартово произведение 5 цветов на 12 скотин.

Comment: точно! =) меня сбил с точку еще один цикл из вики - десятилетний ))